# Mount storage from Fiber Channel SAN on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, storage, mount, mount-point, san

I have a scenario where my shared storage is available at SAN (Storage Area Network). The SAN is available through Fiber Channel. I am installing some oracle product and want to use storage from SAN only. The problem I am facing regarding 'mount' of location from SAN to my Linux machine. Can anyone please assist me for this.
Attached the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can see HP 3par storage system and a LUN which is accessible at least via 4 ports. Treat this LUN as usual: check multiplying, create filesystem on it, mount and use. Or I do not understand the issue. So what is the actual problem?